# Highlighting duplicate rows based on 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following data:

```
Title                                         | Volume | Price
---------------------------------------------------------------
Girl Friends Omnibus                          | 1      | 9.99
Girl Friends Omnibus                          | 2      | 9.99
Kisses, Sighs and Cherry Blossom Pink Omnibus | 1      | 9.99
Hana & Hina After School                      | 1      | 5.99
Hana & Hina After School                      | 2      | 8.99
Girl Friends Omnibus                          | 2      | 8.99
Girl Friends Omnibus                          | 3      | 9.99
```

If I wanted to use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates I'd use the "Format Unique or Duplicate Values" conditional formatting rule. However if I did that it would look for duplicates of just one row, so for the first column only `Kisses, Sighs and Cherry Blossom Pink Omnibus` would not be highlighted.

What I want, however, is for the highlighting to only occur if the first *two* columns are not unique. So only `Girl Friends Omnibus` Volume 2 should be highlighted. The price should not factor at all. In a sense `Title` and `Volume` serve to create a composite Primary Key if they were in a database.

When I try to look this up I get variations of [this](http://spreadsheetpro.net/comparing-two-columns-unique-values/) which highlights values in one column if they exist in another. This won't work for me since the example data shows that the two aren't comparable.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done simply by using the `COUNTIFS()` function:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Select the appropriate cells in the table, making sure that `A2` is the active cell, and enter the following for the conditional formatting formula:

```dart
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A2,$B$2:$B$8,$B2)>1
```

While this works for the simple cases, more advanced situations might require a different technique using `SUMPRODUCT()`. It would be a good idea to learn how to use this more advanced technique. (I always use instead of using `COUNTIFS()`.)

The more advanced equivalent to the above formula would be:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=$A2)*($B$2:$B$8=$B2))>1
```

Answer (score 3):

**This issue can be solved by use of Helper Column also.**

[image]

**Follow these steps:**

1. In Cell E238 write this formula: `=A238&B238` & Fill it down.
2. **Select A238:B244.**
3. From Home Tab Click, **Conditional Formatting**.
4. From the poped up menu click, **New Rule**.
5. Then From the **Rule Type** click, **Use Formula To Determine Which Cells
   to Format.**
6. In **Format Values Where This Formula Is True** enter this formula:
   `=COUNTIF($E$238:$E$244,$E238)>1`
7. Then hit **Format Button** & apply an appropriate color format and
   press **Ok** & on the next screen finish with **Ok**.

*You get both duplicate rows will be highlighted as you can find also in the attached screen shot.*

**N.B.** *You can adjust the Cell addres in both formulas according to your need.*